# When do constructors of static members of template classes get called in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, static-members

There is plenty of information on when constructors of static members of ordinary classes are called.  However, I am seeing some strange behavior with regard to template classes.

What should the output of the following program be?  (Note I use printf to avoid any static initialization order fiasco complications with std::cout.)

```
#include <iostream>

class B {
public:
  B(const std::string &s) { printf("Hello I am B from %s\n", s.c_str()); }
};

template<typename T>
class Atempl {
public:
  static B b_;
};

class A {
public:
  static B b_;
};

template<typename T>
B Atempl<T>::b_("Atempl");
B A::b_("A");

class C : public Atempl<int> {
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  return 0;
}
```

I think the output should be:

```
Hello I am B from A
Hello I am B from Atempl
```

But with g++ 4.3 on FreeBSD 7.3 I get:

```
Hello I am B from A
```

If I add the line

```
template class Atempl<int>;
```

all is well and I get the expected output.  The question is, why  doesn't the declaration of class C count as an instantiation of the template 
    Atempl
and cause B's constructor to be called?  Is this part of the standard or a bug in g++ 4.3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a class template, when performing implicit instantiation, the members are instantiated on demand. Since the code does not use the static member, it is not even instantiated in the whole application.

When you do an explicit intantiation, the whole class and all of its members are instantiated, and that includes the static member variable, which is then initialized and you get your expected result.

Without the explicit instantiation you could do something like `B* p = &Atempl<int>::b_;` (or any other use of the static member) to trigger the instantiation.

Comment: This seems to be correct.  Is this the relevant part of the standard?  The standard says (in Section 14.7.1 of ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E))

_... in particular, the initialization (and any associated side-effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist._

Comment: @Manish: Right §14.7.1/1 contains that quote, but there is another one a couple of paragraphs below: §14.7.1/7 *The implicit instantiation of a class template does not cause any static data members of that class to be implicitly instantiated.*

Answer (score 3):

When a static member of a class template template is initialized is
unspecified.  In fact, unless you actuall use the static member, it
should not be instantiated, and so never be initialized.  If you
explicitly instantiate the template, you force the instantiation of all
of the members, which in turn forces the initialization (but I think
exactly when it will be initialized is still unspecified).

Comment: +1 overall, on the specifics of where it is instantiated, I believe that is in §14.6.4.1/1: *For a [...] or static data member of a class template, [...(a case that does not apply here) Otherwise,] the point of instantiation for such a specialization immediately follows the namespace scope declaration or definition that refers to the specialization.*  I have stripped contents for brevity (else it won't fit a comment, but this case is not considered in the first [...] and falls in the *Otherwise* case.

Comment: But the point of instantiation of a static data member doesn't have any effect on the order of initialization.  In this respect, the instantiated member does not behave the same as a normal class member.  (The reason for this, of course, is that it might be instantiated in several different source files, and of course, initialization will still only occur once.)

Comment: Right, I misunderstood *instantiation* by *initialization*. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

They are called by the C++ runtime sometime after the start of the process and before `main()` is called. There is no difference between 'regular' classes and class template instances. The order in which the constructors are called is undefined.