# C++ template: The static member in a global object is not initialized

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, initialization, static-members

I have a piece of simple C++ code, in which I defined a template and a global object by specializing the template. The object constructor accesses a static member in the specialized template. But it turns out the static member is not initialized at that point. But for a local object (defined in the body of a function), it works. I'm confused...

My c++ compiler is: g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609

```
/////////////////////////
template<typename T>
class TB{
public:
  const char *_name;
  TB(const char * str):_name(str){
    cout << "constructor is called:" << _name << endl;
  };

  virtual ~TB(){
    cout << "destructor is called:" << _name << endl;
  };
};

template<typename T>
class TA{
public:
  const char *_name;
  TA(const char * str):_name(str){
    cout << "constructor is called:" << _name << endl;
    cout << tb._name <<endl;
  };

  virtual ~TA(){
    cout << "destructor is called:" << _name << endl;
  };

  static TB<T> tb;
};

template<typename T>
  TB<T> TA<T>::tb("static-tb");
TA<int> ta("global-ta");

int main(int argc,char ** argv){
  cout << "program started." << endl;
  cout << "program stopped." << endl;
  return 0;
}

/////////////////////////
//  OUTPUT:
constructor is called:global-ta
// yes, only such a single line.
```

If I put the definition of ta in main() like the following, it works.

```
int main(int argc,char ** argv){
  cout << "program started." << endl;
  TA<int> ta("local-ta");
  cout << "program stopped." << endl;
  return 0;
}

/////////////////////
//  OUTPUT:
constructor is called:static-tb
program started.
constructor is called:local-ta
static-tb
program stopped.
destructor is called:local-ta
destructor is called:static-tb
// end of output
```

Comment: Can you try a different compiler, such as Clang or GCC 7?

Comment: change the `cout` to `printf` see the output.  `TB<T> TA<T>::tb("static-tb");` is not instantiated, ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959665/when-do-constructors-of-static-members-of-template-classes-get-called-in-c?rq=1

Comment: why even "program started" was not printed？

Comment: @JohnZwinck I could reproduce it with VS2015.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the first scenario, your program crashed before main started. It crashes inside the constructor of `ta` because it accesses `tb` which was not yet constructed. This is a form of the *Static Initialization Order Fiasco*

The second scenario was successful because `ta` is inside `main`, and that guaranteed that `tb` which is non-local, was constructed before `ta`.

The question is, why in the first scenario, `ta` was constructed before `tb` even though `tb` and `ta` were defined in the same compilation unit, with `tb` defined before `ta`?

Knowing that `tb` is a template static data member, [this quote from cppreference applies:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

> **Dynamic initialization**
>
> After all static initialization is completed,
>   dynamic initialization of non-local variables occurs in the following
>   situations:
>
> 1) Unordered dynamic initialization, which applies only to (static/thread-local) variable templates **and (since C++11) class template static data members** that aren't explicitly specialized. **Initialization of such static variables is indeterminately sequenced with respect to all other dynamic initialization** except if the program starts a thread before a variable is initialized, in which case its initialization is unsequenced (since C++17). Initialization of such thread-local variables is unsequenced with respect to all other dynamic initialization.

So there's no sequence guaranteed here! Since `ta` is a static variable with an *explicit* template specialization, the compiler was allowed to initialize it before `tb`.

Another quote from the same page says:

> **Early dynamic initialization**
>
> The compilers are allowed to initialize dynamically-initialized variables as part of static initialization (essentially, at compile time), if the following conditions are both true:
>
> 1) the dynamic version of the initialization does not change the value of any other object of namespace scope prior to its initialization
>
> 2) the static version of the initialization produces the same value in the initialized variable as would be produced by the dynamic initialization if all variables not required to be initialized statically were initialized dynamically. Because of the rule above, if initialization of some object o1 refers to an namespace-scope object o2, which potentially requires dynamic initialization, but is defined later in the same translation unit, it is unspecified whether the value of o2 used will be the value of the fully initialized o2 (because the compiler promoted initialization of o2 to compile time) or will be the value of o2 merely zero-initialized.

The compiler has decided according to these rules to promote the initialization of `ta` before `tb`. Whether it was promoted to static initialization is not clear, but in any case, it seems pretty clear that the sequence of initialization is not guaranteed when it comes to variable templates and static templates members, due to the first quote and the promotion rules of the second quote.

**Solution**

To ensure that `tb` is initialized before it is used, the simplest is to put it inside a wrapper function. I think that this should be somehow a rule of thumb when dealing with static templates members:

```
template<typename T>
class TA{
    //...
    static TB<T>& getTB();
};

template<typename T>
TB<T>& TA<T>::getTB()
{ static TB<T> tb("static-tb");
  return tb;
}
```

Comment: `tb` is not a variable template; it's a static data member of a class template. Also, if you just c&p from cppreference, the (since...) markers get confusing.

Comment: @A.S.H Thank you very much! This solution works for me. Also, the explanation and citation are helpful. I feel the compiler is able to capture the dependency so that it should be able to come up with a nicer order of initialization.

Comment: @WeijiaSong I am glad to know that this was helpful :). It's probably feasible that the compiler does a dependency analysis on the static variables but in practice it seems that the problem appeared to be very difficult especially with templates, that's why the standard does not mandate such an analysis. Personally, I use the wrapper function systematically whenever in doubt.

Comment: I just stumble into a similar problem and wanted to tried out your code, however it is not very clear how are you using the wrapper function. Do you still keep `TB<T> tb` as memeber of `TA`? Are you initializing that like `template <typename T> TB<T> TA<T>::tb = TA<T>::getTB()`? I just tried that and it still only prints `constructor is called:global-ta`. Could you post the full correct code, please?

Comment: @BRabbit27 No, there's no longer a `tb` member in the class. `tb` is just a "local" (but static) variable in the function `getTb()`. Wherever your code wants to access `tb`, forget about the name `tb` and simply use `getTb()`. i.e. `TA::getTb().doSomething()`. Hope this helps.