# Trying to eliminate .activate and .select in VBA, getting Error 1004 instead when trying to SET range

Tags: vba, excel

Deeply frustrated by Excel VBA as I am trying to avoid having to switch between source and destination for a series of copy/paste or pasteSpecial operations.

Here is a fragment of the problem code:

```
Dim wbkSource As Workbook
Dim wbkDest As Workbook    
Dim rngOutput As Range    
Dim iCol As Integer ' Used for destination paste

Set wbkSource = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbkDest = ActiveWorkbook 'After adding destination workbook

    iCol = 1
    **Set rngOutput = wbkDest.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(1, iCol)**
```

The highlighted line always generates Runtime error 1004, "Application-defined or object-defined error."

What the heck am I doing wrong? I had the code working with activating each workbook in turn, and selecting destination cells, but that is SO ugly and inefficient.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: `.Cells(1, iCol)`. The format (row, col) goes with `.Cells`, which also returns a Range. The method `.Range` uses string like `A1`.

Comment: @A.S.H you've missed on a lot of easy points :) just had to write 1 a line or 2 as "explanation"

Comment: @ShaiRado you know that I love the earn my points "*the hard way*" :P

Comment: @ShaiRado well tbh actually [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42743520/4926357) exhausted me

Comment: I completely understand how that goes A.S.H. It's just the name of the game when you don't want/don't have time to write a full response that meets your own standards

Comment: @Alister If my answer provides a sufficient solution to the problem, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A.S.H in the comments got it right, credit to him, but it appears he didn't have time to post a full response and chose a comment instead.

A Range is a range, and a single cell can also be a range.

The syntax is:

```
Cells([rowindex],[columnindex])
```

and Range is

```
Range([cell1],[cell2])
```

The following is also acceptable (as ugly as it looks)

```
Range(Cells(1,1),Cells(2,2))  'Equivalent to 

Range("A1:B2")

'Also this crazy mess works too

Dim intRow As Integer: intRow = 1
Cells("A" & intRow)
Range("A1:B" & intRow)
```

And the final answer to correct your issue:

```
Set rngOutput = wbkDest.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, iCol)
```

I hope this helps and I'm glad you're getting away from .Activate and .Select!

Comment: For completeness you might also add the `Range(String)` syntax i.e. `.Range("A1") :)

Comment: ooh and Range("A" & integer) messes too?

Comment: Also, technically I did, it's in the 'commented out part though heh

Comment: Thank you everyone! Of course, you know how it goes—very shortly after letting-off steam by posting my question, I realised what I had done wrong, and reached the solution posted by Adam, but didn't know enough about Stack Overflow to come and answer my own question. Sorry. However, I have another question. Is there a method other than Set which will keep rngOutput updated as the value of iCol changes? I seem to require a separate Set command each time I increment iCol. Am I missing something else?